# Handling File Naming Convention from Configuration File

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have attempting to implement a file naming convention in my program. For example I have a configuration file such as below:

```
MyConfig.conf
# File naming convention for output-file
[Field1][Field3][Field2]
```

'FieldX' corresponds with string within the program - so for example a program would read the configuration file and format the strings as follows in the program:

```
Field1Value Field2Value Field3Value
```

Are there any preferred ways to do this kind of thing in C#?

Comment: you mean, FieldX can be configured to be any string? then you just rearrange/format the FieldX to create a file name?

or do you mean that the rearrangement should be the one configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to use app settings. The app settings contain the string format that you need. Then you just use that string format.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _16852548
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

            string field1Value = "Filename";
            string field2Value = ".";
            string field3Value = "txt";

            string fileFormat = appSettings["FileNameFormat"];

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(fileFormat, field1Value, field2Value, field3Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Then the config file can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FileNameFormat" value="{0}{2}{1}"/> <!-- follow string.Format syntax -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```